# what is the clientIP in namecheap api request?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, namecheap

According to namecheap api docs, a request should have this structure:

```
response_request = f'https://api.namecheap.com/xml.response?ApiUser={ApiUser}&ApiKey={ApiKey}&UserName={ApiUser}&Command=namecheap.domains.check&ClientIp={ClientIp}&DomainList={DomainList}'
```

But I keep receiving  ***Error Number="1011150" Invalid request IP*** when I input ClientIp as my IP address (I use a shared IP).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ClientIp is:

- The public IP address of the system making the request. Google search for "What is my IP" for several services that will provide your public IP address.
- The same public IP address must be **whitelisted**. This [link](https://www.namecheap.com/support/api/intro/) provides details on **Whitelisting IP**.